# Return a value when using jQuery.each()?

Tags: jquery, each

I want to return false and return from function if I find first blank textbox

```
function validate(){
 $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "")
     return false;
});
}
```

and above code is not working for me :(
can anybody help?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are jumping out, but from the *inner* loop, I would instead use a selector for your specific "no value" check, like this:

```
function validate(){
  if($('input[type=text][value=""]').length) return false;
}
```

Or, set the result as you go inside the loop, and return *that* result from the outer loop:

```
function validate() {
  var valid = true;
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "") //or a more complex check here
      return valid = false;
  });
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: @Nick Craver, It is a very old post but I have a question. Is there any risk above that function return `true` before `each` loop completed?

Comment: Absolutely zero such risk because until .each() completes, it will not proceed to the last statement. @YahyaE

Comment: The first example does not work when you need to trim the value first. The second example works, but it relies on a state variable, which is generally fine, but in case you wanted to do pure functional programming it would not be considered valid.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it like this:

```
function validate(){
    var rv = true;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            rv = false;   // Set flag
            return false; // Stop iterating
        }
    });
    return rv;
}
```

That assumes you want to return `true` if you don't find it.

You may find that this is one of those sitautions where you don't want to use `each` at all:

```
function validate(){
    var inputs = $('input[type=text]');
    var index;
    while (index = inputs.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
        if (inputs[index].value == "") { // Or $(inputs[index]).val() == "" if you prefer
            return false;
        }
    }
    // (Presumably return something here, though you weren't in your example)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to existing answers to clear the behavior of `$(selector).each` and why it doesn't respect return false in OP's code.

`return` keyword inside `$(selector).each` is used to break or continue the loop. If you use `return false`, it is equivalent to a `break` statement inside a `for/while` loop. Returning non-false is the same as a `continue` statement in a `for` loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Because you're returning false, the loop breaks and the function ends up returning `undefined` in your case. 
Your option is to use a var outside `$.each` or avoid using it altogether as @TJCrowder wrote.