# How to return a value from $.each(...)?

Tags: jquery, arrays, scope, each

*To intercept a gazillion of close-votes, I can stress that it's not related to, let alone answered by, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820269/return-a-value-when-using-jquery-each).*

I'm not sure how to return a value from a *$.each(...)* construction to the outer scope. Suppose that we have an array of JSON objects (or of arrays for that matter).

```
var output = "";
$.each(array, function (key1, value1) {
  output += "[" + key1 + "] --> ";
  $.each(value1, function (key2, value2) {
    output += key2 + ":" + value2 + " ";
  });
});
console.log(output);
```

Right now, as the example above illustrates, I'm relying on a predeclared *output* that I write to from each of the sub-levels of scope. It works. However, I can't stop feeling that it's not the best approach. I'd like to return something, instead of appending it to the semi-global *output*.

Comment: you can't return something out of $.each, what you are doing is pretty much the way you have to do it. the only alternative is executing a function with the value inside the each instead.

Comment: @KevinB Dang... Thanks. No room for improvement. I guess my code is perfect.   :D

Comment: use `for` loop and `for..in` :)

Comment: @sabithpocker How is that going to help? I **definitely** can't return anything from a loop, can I?

Comment: @KonradViltersten May I suggest changing `array` to `obj`? JS doesn't have key => val (associative) arrays. :)

Comment: you can definitely `return` from a loop, but returning will return from the `function`. Writing the same thing with `for` and `for..in` makes the idea more clear, and got some performance gains if that matters.

Comment: YOu can definitely return from a for loop. However, in your case, you can actually use $.map pretty effectively.

Comment: @sabithpocker I thought that a *return* in a loop would kick me out of the **function** that the loop is in (instead of kicking me out just one level to the outer loop). Perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: you are not mistaken `return` will return from the function. breaking out of iterations can be done with `break`, skipping iteration can be done with `continue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return statement in `.each()` return whether or not if the loop continue. To have a `.each()` returning a value, you can use `.map()` like that :

```
var output = $.map(array, function(v, i){
    return "[" + i + "] --> " + $.map(v, function(v, i){
        return i+ ':' + v + ' ';        
    }).join();
}).join();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/stEV6/

But personnaly, I prefer the way you do it: with a varible.

Comment: Actually the native `.map()` method can be used here as well

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `return` - try [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead:

```
var output = array.reduce(function(p, value1, key1) {
    var nested = value1.reduce(function(p, value2, key2) {
        return [p, key2, ':', value2, ' '].join('');
    }, '');

    return [p, '[', key1, '] --> ', nested].join('');
}, '');
console.log(output);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2chJ/

Comment: Didnt know about that function, i gotta thank you for learning something!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return value from `$.each()`, if you return true (or any non false) this means `continue` and if you return false this means `break` - this happens because `$.each()` just loops and runs your anonymous function (the `return` statement runs in your anonymous function and that is the way `$.each()` was programmed to handle the returned value).

If you really really have to do this wrap it in a function like so:

```
function myFunction(){
    var output = '';
    $.each(something,function(){
        output += 'some text'
    })
    return output;
}
```